# PostgreSQL window function: partition with condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, postgresql-performance

I'm trying to create a query with fields:

- data - Date sequence
- user_id - User ID
- is_paid - Did the user pay this month
- number_of_not_paid - the number of months since the last payment, if the payment is in this month, then 0

```
select
   date,
   user_id,
   is_paid,
   (case when is_paid
       then 0
       else sum(case when is_paid then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by user_id order by date)
   end)
from data
```

The result I get is:

| date | user_id | is_paid | num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | true | 0 |
| 2020-02-01 | 1 | false | 1 |
| 2020-03-01 | 1 | false | 2 |
| 2020-04-01 | 1 | true | 0 |
| 2020-05-01 | 1 | false | **3** |
| 2020-06-01 | 1 | true | 0 |

And the result I would like to get is:

| date | user_id | is_paid | num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | true | 0 |
| 2020-02-01 | 1 | false | 1 |
| 2020-03-01 | 1 | false | 2 |
| 2020-04-01 | 1 | true | 0 |
| 2020-05-01 | 1 | false | **1** |
| 2020-06-01 | 1 | true | 0 |

How I can fix my query for correct result?

Comment: Explain little bit more what does this imply ? You want to sum only when is_paid = false and when it is in a row ? When it is break by a true then you want to start from 1 again ?

Comment: i think you'll need `recursive` for this. _check `is_paid` and if it is false add 1 to the previous value in the same field, else put 0_

Comment: @VBoka Yes, you got it right

Comment: here's an example of how `recursive` can help you -- [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aPBdi4ZkWPu4mZtDLn5c46/0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to reset the delinquency timer every time the user pays, so first mark each time the user pays (`boolean` can be cast to `int` to be summed):

```
with runs as (
  select date, user_id, is_paid, 
         sum(is_paid::int) over (partition by user_id
                                     order by date) as run_number
    from my_table
)
```

With these runs marked, you can then sum the preceding `false` values within the `(user_id, run_number)` window:

```
select date, user_id, is_paid,
       sum((not is_paid)::int) over (partition by user_id, run_number
                                         order by date) as num
  from runs;

 date       | user_id | is_paid | num
 :--------- | ------: | :------ | --:
 2020-01-01 |       1 | t       |   0
 2020-02-01 |       1 | f       |   1
 2020-03-01 |       1 | f       |   2
 2020-04-01 |       1 | t       |   0
 2020-05-01 |       1 | f       |   1
 2020-06-01 |       1 | t       |   0
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e57063e7af5994361bb60bbcacd2e313)*

Comment: I think it's a bit complicated. Could I use `rows between ... and ...` for my query?

Comment: @NPreston If you can figure out a way to apply rows, groups, or ranges to achieve this result, then please post your solution as I would like to learn how that is done.